# Prisma: How to get position of a record after sort in prisma?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

I have a waitlist where users signup with their email. Then they can use their invite code and invite more users.
I am sorting users by the number of users they have invited. I am sorting like this:

```
const x = await prisma.user.findMany({
select: {
  id: true,
  email: true,
},
orderBy: {
  createdUsers: {
    _count: "desc",
  },
},});
```

This is the schema:

```
  model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  email  String  @unique 
  inviteCode String @unique @default(cuid())
  createdById     Int?    
  createdBy       User?       @relation("UserCreatedBy", fields: [createdById], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  createdUsers    User[]   @relation("UserCreatedBy")
}
```

What i want to do is basically tell them the position of the user in the waitlist based on the number of users they have invited.
Any help will be appreciated?